# Inserir comando do msdos em um arquivo vbscript

Tags: vbs, ms-dos

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como fazer para inserir uma linha de comando do MsDos dentro de um vbscript.

Tenho essa linha de comando para pegar o ID do programa Anydesk, disponível no site do Anydesk

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --get-id') do set CID=%%i 
echo AnyDesk ID is = %CID%
pause
```

Que gera esse resultado no prompt de comando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se é possível rodar ou converter para vbscript, a finalidade é usar a função "msgbox" para captar o ID que o comando no msdos capta e exibe no prompt, tendo um resultado parecido com esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como rodar comando msdos dentro de um vbscript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433672/como-rodar-comando-msdos-dentro-de-um-vbscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não testada com a saída do **AnyDesk.exe**, então pode ocorrer da saída não se dar no:

***`WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll`***

Daí teria que trocar para:

***`WshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll`***

---

---

```
strCommand = "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"" --get-id "
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
strOutput = "AnyDesk ID is = "& strOutput
MsgBox strOutput, 64, "AnyDesk ID"
```

---

- Para fazer a mesma coisa e por uma cópia do ID no seu **`ClipBoard`** **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**`+`**<kbd>C</kbd>**

---

```
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"" --get-id |clip", 0, True
 strOutput = CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
 MsgBox strOutput, 64, "AnyDesk ID"
```

Comment: Perfeito!!!
Era o que precisava, me atende perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.
Obs* Na segunda opção que passou, após clicar em OK gera um erro.

Comment: @M.Nunes depois tento ver a segundo, mas qual Windows vc usa. Boa pergunta a sua! Obrigado.

Comment: Na primeira opção que passou, como faço para que o cmd strCommand = "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"" --get-id " rode invisível

Comment: @M.Nunes vejo p vc mais tarde... agora no trabalho... zOk?

Comment: @M.Nunes  tentei algumas opções e n funcionou, vou insistir... mas dentro do meu tempo, zOk?

Comment: eu agradeço pela ajuda, já pesquisei muito como ocultar a chamada do prompt, mas até agora sem sucesso.